# Проверка выпадающего списка с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-form

Подскажите пожалуйста! Как реализовать в данной [форме](http://alfa.rbrbank.ru/clients/private/crediting/consumer/online_form_ufa.php) проверку выпадающего списка по выбору региона с помощью *jQuery*.
Пробовал несколько вариантов, но ни один не отрабатывает.

**Вариант 1:**

```
$('#region').change(function (){
    /*
     * В переменную region положим значение селекта
     * (выбранный регион)
     */
    var region = $(this).val();
    /*
     * Если значение селекта равно 0,
     * т.е. не выбран регион, тогда
     * выводим сообщение
     */ 
    if (region == '0') {
        alert('Вы не выбрали регион проживания!');
        return(false);
    }
    });
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
function validateForm() {
        if ( document.qform.region.selectedIndex == 0 ){
                alert("Вы не выбрали регион проживания!");
        }
    }
```

**Вариант 3:**

```
function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms['qform']['region'].value;
        if (x == 0) {
            alert("Вы не выбрали регион проживания!");
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if($("#region").val() == 0) return false;
});
```

Comment: а это куда? о_О
Напишите пожалуйста код целиком

Comment: за формой, или    `$(function(){})`    в любом месте

Comment: Все понял, спасибо сделал :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
$("#region option:selected").val();
```

или

```
$("#region :selected").val();
```

Comment: Сделал, но она начала отрабатывать при загрузке страницы, а как сделать чтобы при отправке формы?

Comment: val() тянется и без option:selected